# Definition of convergence to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following definition hold true for every series that converges to infinity?

**Definition-** A sequence $x_n$ is said to converge to $\infty$ if, for every $a>0$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$, such that for $n>N$ it is true that $|x_n-a|>\epsilon$

Clarification: For example we can use this definition to determine that $x_n=\sqrt{n}$ converges to infinity. But if our sequence is $1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5...$ then the above definition can't be used.

Can this definition be modified so that oscillating sequences can also be tested for convergence to infinity?

Comment: Are you really interested in series? Or in sequences?

Comment: Your title and your first sentence are about different notions (convergence to infinity vs. does not converge).

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. First of all, what you wrote was the definition of converging to $\infty$ by **sequences**, not **series**. Second, how can a definition "hold true" for a series? A definition is what it is, a definition. It is not something that can be true or false, it's just a definition.

Comment: I have tried to make the question more clear.

Comment: @5xum I am trying to write what would the definition of a sequence that converges to infinity look like.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar The sequence $1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5, \dots$ has no limit and it does not converge to $+\infty$ (although it is unbounded). On the other hand, the oscillating sequence $1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4, \dots$ has no limit, it does not converge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ but it does satisfy your definition. See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses.

Comment: Sequences never *converge* to infinity, although they might *diverge* to infinity. (Some people might use the phrase "converge to infinity" but it doesn't really make sense, at least in spaces which lack a point at infinity. Going to infinity is a special type of divergence, not a special type of convergence).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a sequence $(x_n)_n$, if for every $a>0$ and for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$, such that, for $n>N$ it is true that $|x_n-a|>\epsilon$ then 
$$|x_n|+|a|\geq |x_n-a|>\epsilon\implies |x_n|>\epsilon-|a|$$
and therefore, by the arbitrarity of $a$ and $\epsilon$
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}|x_n|=+\infty.$$
Also the other implication holds. More simply, a definition of $\lim_{n\to +\infty}|x_n|=+\infty$ should be: for every $a>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$, such that, for $n>N$ it is true that $|x_n|>a$ (no need of the $\epsilon$ part).

The sequence $1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5, \dots$ has no limit and it does not converge to $+\infty$ (although it is unbounded). On the other hand, the oscillating sequence $1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4, \dots$ has no limit, it does not converge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ but it does satisfy your definition.

Answer (score 2):

> But if our sequence is $1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5...$ then the above definition can't be used.

Yes, it can. The definition can be used to come to a conclusion that the above sequence **does not** converge to $\infty$.

---

> Can this definition be modified so that oscillating sequences can also be tested for convergence to infinity.

The definition already **can** be used to test for convergence of oscillating sequences to infinity. Using the definition, it can be proven that such sequences **do not** converge to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition is: a sequence $x_n$ is said to converging to $+\infty$, if

$$\forall a\in \mathbb{R} \quad \exists N\in \mathbb{N}\quad n>N \implies x_n>a$$

Note that we don’t need to set $a>0$ and we don’t needi $\epsilon$ for the definition.